# Django: Send a SELECT value inside form action url

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a form with multiple `select` inputs, as below:

```
<form method="POST" class="row" action="{% url 'solution_product_list'  %}">
{% csrf_token %}
    {#  main select div: usage or model? #}
    <div class="col-md-3 mx-md-5">
        <h2 class="h5 nm-text-color fw-bold mb-4">انتخاب بر اساس:</h2>
        <select required aria-label="Select usage or model" id="usage_model_select" class="form-select" onchange="set_usage_or_model_dic()">
            <option selected>----</option>
            <option value="usage">کاربرد</option>
            <option value="model">مدل</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    {#  usage or model select div #}
    <div class="col-md-3 mx-md-5">
    {#  usage select div #}
        <div class="usage visually-hidden" id="usage_div">
            <h2 class="h5 nm-text-color fw-bold mb-4">انتخاب کاربرد:</h2>
            <select required aria-label="Select usage" class="form-select"
                    name="usage_select" onchange="set_sub_usage_list()" id="usage_select_id">
                <option selected>----</option>
                {% for usage in usage_queryset %}
                    <option value="{{ usage.id }}">{{ usage.usage_name_fa }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    {#  model select div #}
        <div class="model visually-hidden" id="model_div">
            <h2 class="h5 nm-text-color fw-bold mb-4">انتخاب مدل:</h2>
            <select required aria-label="Select model" class="form-select"
                    name="model_select" onchange="set_pump_type_list()" id="model_select_id">
                <option selected>----</option>
                {% for model in main_model_queryset %}
                    <option value="{{ model.id }}">{{ model.model_name_fa }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    {# select sub_usage or pump_type div #}
    <div class="col-md-3 mx-md-5">
    {#  sub_usage select div #}
        <div class="sub_usage visually-hidden" id="sub_usage_div">
            <h2 class="h5 nm-text-color fw-bold mb-4">انتخاب کاربرد جزئی:</h2>
            <select required aria-label="Select sub_usage" class="form-select" name="sub_usage_select">
                <option selected>همه‌ی کابردهای جزئی</option>
                {% for sub_usage in sub_usage_queryset %}
                    <option value="{{ sub_usage.id }}">{{ sub_usage.sub_usage_name_fa }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    {#  model select div #}
        <div class="pump-type visually-hidden" id="pump_type_div">
            <h2 class="h5 nm-text-color fw-bold mb-4">انتخاب تیپ:</h2>
            <select aria-label="Select pump_type" class="form-select" name="pump_type_select">
                <option selected>همه‌ی تیپ‌های این مدل</option>
                {% for pump_type in pump_type_queryset %}
                    <option value="{{ pump_type.id }}">{{ pump_type.type_name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="مرحله بعدی" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, the action of my form is `"{% url 'solution_product_list'  %}"`, but I'd like to send the selected value (from any select inputs that has been selected) to this action url, as it would be `{% url 'solution_product_list' selected_value %}`. I did some searches and came accross to these questions which suggested using `redirect`:

[Django form action url dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448271/django-form-action-url-dynamic)

[How to send selected option value in form action in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042107/how-to-send-selected-option-value-in-form-action-in-django)

[Django : HTML form action directing to view (or url?) with 2 arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440962/django-html-form-action-directing-to-view-or-url-with-2-arguments)

[Dynamic URL routing from html form within action in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73602673/dynamic-url-routing-from-html-form-within-action-in-django)

But none the above helped me, or maybe I could not understand the solutions there. Can anyone please help me on this matter?

Also I have a messy `view` for this page, as below:

```
def solution_product_list(request):
    product_list_queryset = None
    sub_usage_list = []
    pump_type_list = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST["usage_select"] != "----":
            usage_select = request.POST["usage_select"]
            product_list_queryset = Product.objects.filter(usage__id=usage_select)
            sub_usage_list = SubUsage.objects.filter(usage__id=usage_select)
            if request.POST["sub_usage_select"] != "همه‌ی کابردهای جزئی":
                sub_usage_select = request.POST["sub_usage_select"]
                product_list_queryset = Product.objects.filter(
                    sub_usage__id=sub_usage_select
                )
        elif request.POST["model_select"] != "----":
            model_select = request.POST["model_select"]
            product_list_queryset = Product.objects.filter(main_model__id=model_select)
            pump_type_list = PumpType.objects.filter(
                main_model__id=model_select
            )
            if request.POST["pump_type_select"] != "همه‌ی تیپ‌های این مدل":
                pump_type_select = request.POST["pump_type_select"]
                product_list_queryset = Product.objects.filter(
                    pump_type__id=pump_type_select
                )
        elif request.POST["head"] and request.POST["flow"]:
            flow = float(request.POST["flow"])
            head = float(request.POST["head"])
            head_flow_list_main = get_head_flow_list(product_list_queryset)
            product_list = return_filtered_products(
                head_flow_list_main, head, flow
            )
            product_list_queryset = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_list)
    page = request.GET.get("page", 1)
    paginator = Paginator(product_list_queryset, 10)
    try:
        product_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        product_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        product_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    queryset_dictionary = get_common_queryset()
    page_context = {
        "product_list": product_list_queryset,
        "sub_usage_queryset": sub_usage_list,
        "pump_type_queryset": pump_type_list,
    }
    print(product_list_queryset)
    context = {
        **queryset_dictionary,
        **page_context,
    }
    return render(request, "solutions/second_stage_select.html", context)
```

I'm relatively new to Django, so if you can give me any advice on better code formatting or writing, your notes will be most appreciated.

Comment: I think this post solution contains your answer too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72540076/how-to-display-selected-option-value-selected-in-option-tag-in-django-template-f

Comment: @SeyedJavadAdabikhosh I can't understand how it is related to my problem, can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1):

Although it's better to use form widgets to manage this situations but another solution is:
 `selected_lang = request.POST.get('lang_txt')`
So your code in view could be as follow:
`usage_select = request.POST.get('usage_select')`

And in your html template you can do as follow to maintain and display previos selected options using your context:

```
<option value="span_to_eng" {% if data.selected_lang == 'span_to_eng' %}selected{% endif %}>Spanish To English</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, you set the values of the context when there is a `post` method, but you do not return an i.e. `HttpResponse` or `redirect` object.

let's solve your problem with less code, you can get the idea:

`views.py`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def first_stage(request):
    extra_context_from_view = ["opt1", "opt2", "opt3"]

    context = {
        "extra_context_from_view": extra_context_from_view,
        "previously_saved_val_db": "opt2",
    }
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST["first_stage"]:
            context = {"forward_to_second_stage": request.POST["first_stage"]}
        # in the case of redirect uncomment two below line 
        # and you should comment the second_stage render 
        # request.session['redirected_context'] = {'redirected': 'test'}
        # return redirect("second_stage")
        return render(request, "pages/second_stage.html", context)
    return render(request, "pages/first_stage.html", context)

def second_stage(request):
    context = {"second_view": "from_second_view"}
    return render(request, "pages/second_stage.html", context)
```

`first_stage.html`

```html
{% comment %}
remove this line if it is not necessary
{% if val == previously_saved_val_db %}selected{% endif %} 

it is just an example to show you how to dynamically set the
value attribute of a tag in HTML.
{% endcomment %}

<form method="POST" class="row" action="{% url 'first_stage' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2 class="h5 nm-text-color fw-bold mb-4">Some Header</h2>
    <select name="first_stage">
        <option selected>----</option>
        {% for val in extra_context_from_view %}
            <option value="{{ val }}"
            {% if val == previously_saved_val_db %}selected{% endif %}>{{ val }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

`second_stage.html`

```html
<p> Normal view after post at the same URL (view)</p>
<h1> YOUR SELECT OPTION: {{ forward_to_second_stage }} </h1>

<p> Redirected version at another URL (view)</p>

{% comment %}
pay atention you probably get session value even you do not use 
the redirect method 
{% endcomment %}
{{ request.session.redirected_context }}
<br>
{{ second_view }}
```

`urls.py`:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("first-stage/", views.first_stage, name="first_stage"),
    path("second-stage/", views.second_stage, name="second_stage"),
]
```

if you use the `return render(request, "pages/second_stage.html", context)` the url will not change and the process will be performed at the current view, but with a different template.

P.S:

- Post your question with a minimal reproducible example.
- You can debug your code by printing inside the template.
- You can see what values are passed from the view to the template and vice versa.
- Use something like `IntegerChoices` or `TextChoices` in your model and, use them inside the view for comparison.
- Use `{% trans %}` like tag in template for the labels.

**EDIT**

When the request method is `post` in your code, and the user submits the form, what does happen?

```py
def solution_product_list(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST["usage_select"] != "----":
            # some logic
        elif request.POST["model_select"] != "----":
            # some logic
        elif request.POST["head"] and request.POST["flow"]:
            # some logic
        # ok then ???
    # pagination

    # other logic and updating context
    # do you see in this way the updated context at second_stage_select.html?
    
    return render(request, "solutions/second_stage_select.html", context)
```

Now, you can compare my answer `views.py` and yours. If you comment all the return objects inside the `if request.method == "POST":` it would be the same as your code. So, the rest of the explanation is extra!

1. What is the `extra_context_from_view`?

I do not have access to your models, and it is time consuming to reproduce (if it would be possible even) your problem exactly. So, this value create options for the `select` tag and I am passing it to the template to simulate your problem. You can consider it as `"product_list"` in `page_context = {"product_list": product_list_queryset, ...}`.

2. What is `"previously_saved_val_db"` and how did you set opt2 for it?

Again, it is another context value, to show, how you can use `if/else` inside the template, and set the `selected` attribute of `select` tag. I used this name `previously_saved_val_db` , because it gives the sense that, if previously, for one of your models object, you have already a value in db, and you want to set it for `select` tag automatically. Do I have a db for your question? No! I use an example value so.

3. Does `request.POST["first_stage"]` return the value of this select tag? Yes, as I told before you can use print to debug the code.
   Use `print(request.POST["first_stage"])` in the `views.py` and `{{ forward_to_second_stage }}` in the template to see them.
4. What does the line `context = {"second_view": "from_second_view"}` mean?  It was another example, to show, that the `second_stage.html` and its view function are working.
   You can comment the `second_stage` function and its path in `urls.py`, you will see that, this time there is no `{"second_view": "from_second_view"}` in the rendered result after post`

[before post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkBZ1.jpg), [render version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMrMN.jpg) , [redirect version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOhox.jpg).

P.S (2). Pay attention, if you want to pass the select option with redirect, you should first add them inside the view, and then use it insde the template, look how I did that for `request.session['redirected_context'] = {'redirected': 'test'}`.

I hope now, it is clear enough!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after even a few tries, I couldn't understand your code. I'm trying to understand and use it, but please clarify a bit more if possible. My questions are: 1- what is `extra_context_from_view`? 2- what is `"previously_saved_val_db"` and how did you set `opt2` for it? 3- Does `request.POST["first_stage"]` return the value of this select tag? 4- What does the line `context = {"second_view": "from_second_view"}` mean?

Comment: just a simple question, did you run my code in your local dev environment? you just need to copy/paste everything and put the template files in a correct folder. your question by the way shows miss understanding the basics. i edit my answer to explain more!

Comment: @A D Nope, I did not run your code because I didn't understand it. And I intend to learn from you so it would be perfect if you could answer the questions above. Thank you for the time and effort you are giving me.

Comment: @A D inorder to use your solution, I'm stuck in the next step :(, where I've asked another question for it. Could you please take a look at that question too? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74912100/set-dynamic-values-from-a-dictionary-for-select-values-inside-a-django-template